# DataGrid moving data down a row, while entering unrelated data

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` which is used for user entry, there is a `ComboBox` at the first column.  The first row works perfect, but on the 2nd or more rows, as soon as I enter any data into one of the `TextBoxes`, the `ComboBox` moves down a row.  None of the textbox cells / data moves.

[image]

There are no attached events, etc., here is the code for the DataGrid. All of the `ElementStyles` are purely cosmetic (i.e., foreground and horizontal alignment).  If anyone has an idea to check why this is happening and/or to stop the ComboBox data from moving, that would be appreciated, I'm at a bit of a loss where to start (I have tried without the styles, without `UserCanAddRows`, etc.).

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2"  Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding PM.Selection.PhysicalProps}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="False" CanUserAddRows="True">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Material" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource lHeader}">
       <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Background="Gray" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.DataLists.Materials, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedIndex="{Binding Material}"/>
                  </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="DN" Binding="{Binding DN, TargetNullValue='', UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource mHeader}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource dgCell}"/>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Wall" Binding="{Binding WT, TargetNullValue='', UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource mHeader}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource dgCell}"/>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Length" Binding="{Binding Length, TargetNullValue='', UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat=N2}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource mHeader}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource dgCell}"/>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Min Head" Binding="{Binding MinH, TargetNullValue='', UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource mHeader}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource dgCell}"/>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Max Head" Binding="{Binding MaxH, TargetNullValue='', UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource mHeader}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource dgCell}"/>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pressure" Binding="{Binding TPressure, TargetNullValue='', UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat=N2}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource rHeader}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource dgCell}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```